# Gorm - AutoMigrate creates duplicate Unique Keys

Tags: mysql, database, go, migration, go-gorm

I have the following Struct/Model

```
type TestTable struct {
    ID      uint `gorm:"unique;autoIncrement"`
    QuoteID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```

If I auto migrate it with gorm wierd things happen:
At first the auto migration doesn't work at all: "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key". Gorm tries to set both columns to autoIncrement. As far as I know this shouldn't happen?
I fixed this issue by setting autoIncrement to false on QuoteID. Everything seems to work fine, but now gorm alters the table on every migration and creates a new unique key every time. id_1, id_2, id_3, and so on. Is there a fix for this?

I already searched the gorm docs for valuable information but couldn't find anything.

Help is appreciated! Have a great day :)